# Como estruturar array multidimensional com json

Tags: php, jquery, json, array

Boa noite!!!
Tenho um json que retorna nesse formato:

```
{rua: "A01", col: "01D", alt: "A"},{rua: "A01", col: "01D", alt: "B"},{rua: "A01", col: "01D", alt: "C"},{rua: "A01", col: "01D", alt: "D"}
```

Mas preciso que retorne nesse formato:

```
{rua: "A01",end:{col: "01D",comp:{alt: "A",alt: "B",alt: "C",alt: "D"}

{rua: "A01",end:{col: "02D",comp:{alt: "A",alt: "B",alt: "C",alt: "D"}
```

O meu php está assim:

```
while ($query=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $array_end[] = array(
        'rua' => $query['rua'],
        'col' => $query['coluna'],
        'alt' => $query['altura'],
    );
}
```

Alguém pode ajudar?
Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para o seu `while` fica assim:

```
while ($query=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
$array_end[] = array(
    'rua' => $query['rua'],
    'end' => array(
         'col' => $query['coluna'],
         'comp' => array('alt' => $query['altura'])
       )
    );
}
```

Comment: Muito bom. Obrigado!!!